# xsl:call-template in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have looked all over google and couldn't figure out how to implement this correctly. It's either not possible at all, or I'm missing some kind of syntax? It's been extremely long since I have done JavaScript, so I may just be missing something very simple.

I have some JavaScript embed into a XSL file using  `<xsl:text disabled-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[` and using XML 1.0.

So I have something like this:

```
    function seconds(s) {
        s = s / 60;

        document.write(s + " ");
        if (s > 2) {
            document.write(s + " " + '<xsl:call-template name="resources"><xsl:with-param name="res" select="minutes"/></xsl:call-template>');
        }
        else {
            document.write(s + " " + '<xsl:call-template name="resources"><xsl:with-param name="res" select="minute"/></xsl:call-template>');
        }
    }
```

So what's going on is that I am given seconds in increment of "60" variable "s". And I need to calculate to minutes, however, I need to call a template to actually print a string "minute" or "minutes". I know the call-template works in XSL. But when I embed it into the JavaScript, it doesn't show "minutes" or "minute". It will only show the corrected integer and the space.

How do I go about embedding this xsl line into JavaScript, or is it at all possible?

Edit:
So I'll try clarify some more. The data on the XML file isn't important. I suppose what my question is, for the document.write line, is there something wrong with embedding the xxl code into it. Because it doesn't actually print whatever the template is suppose to print (which basically is to translate the word "minute/minutes" to whatever language the user chooses or defaults to english if language doesn't exist. Thus not important. I just needed to know what was wrong with the syntax with the document.write line to prevent the XSL code from displaying. Or is it possible to embed that into JavaScript at all? All the JavaScript is done through the CDATA encapsulation on an .xsl file. Hope this clarifies it more.

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically write javascript from an XML document using XSLT, or are you trying to call an XSLT template from Javascript? Can you include a sample XML document and a more complete XSLT?

Comment: Added more clarification, hopefully you're able to help me check the syntax or if this type of embedding is possible.

Comment: You can't run a single XSL command from within Javascript. You reall y need to include more code (if there is any) and really think about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, as it gives the impression you are trying to call an **xsl:template** using Javascript, which is not possible. But I think what you are actually saying is that you are trying to call a template in XSLT as part of outputting some text which just happens to be javascript for later use in a browser.

The reason is not working is because as you say in your question, the javascript text you are outputing is surrounded by this...

```
<xsl:text disabled-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[
  ... Javascript code here..
]]></xsl:text>
```

In particular, the use of the CDATA tag means that XSLT treats everything inside it as unparsed text, and so it irrelevant if you just happen to have some text using xslt syntax. It is just treated as any other text.

What you could do to get around this is to close off the CDATA before each **xsl:call-template** and re-open it after. Something like this

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[
function seconds(s) {
    s = s / 60;

    document.write(s + " ");
    if (s > 2) {
        document.write(s + " " + ']]></xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="resources"><xsl:with-param name="res" select="'minutes'"/></xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[');
    }
    else {
        document.write(s + " " + ']]></xsl:text>
           <xsl:call-template name="resources"><xsl:with-param name="res" select="'minute'"/></xsl:call-template>
           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[');
    }
}
  ]]>
  </xsl:text>
```

Or maybe it is slighty tidier to do away with the outermost **xsl:text** and **CDATA** tags, and only use them to surround characters that contain any 'escape' characters.

```
<xsl:template name="outputSeconds">
function seconds(s) {
    s = s / 60;

    document.write(s + " ");
    if (s <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text> 2) {
        document.write(s + " " + '<xsl:call-template name="resources"><xsl:with-param name="res" select="'minutes'"/></xsl:call-template>');
    }
    else {
        document.write(s + " " + '<xsl:call-template name="resources"><xsl:with-param name="res" select="'minute'"/></xsl:call-template>');
    }
}
</xsl:template>
```

Two things to note:

1) In your question your refer to "disabled-output-escaping" when it should be "disable-output-escaping"

2) Where you call the "resources" template with a parameter, if you want to pass in a string value, as opposed to the value of a node, enclose the value in apostrophes; `<xsl:with-param name="res" select="'minute'"/>`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I didn't know <![CDATA[ could be just ended and continued in the middle of a JavaScript line. I haven't had much experience working with multiple languages combined. But this is adding to my toolbox of knowledge. Thanks again Tim!

Comment: From XSLT's point of view, it is not JavaScript, it is just a bit of text that is being output for something else to use. You can start and end the CDATA where you like!